# how to call any setter method before actionlistener event of rich datascroller

Tags: jsp, richfaces, richdatatable

I want to get the pageno of `rich:datascroller` before action listener event. For the below code binding attribute sets value of `decRm.dataScrollerBind(UIDataScrollar)` after the calling of dataScroller method.

JSP code

```
<rich:dataTable>
    <rich:datascroller id="histScroller" binding="#{decRm.dataScrollerBind}"
        actionListener="#{decRm.dataScroller}" for="decHistID" />
<rich:dataTable>
```

Is it possible to get the pageno of rich data scroller before actionlistener event of data scroller?

Comment: Is it  really JSP? Maybe 'JSP code' should be changed to 'xhtml code'. JSF 2 do not support JSP (even when you use RichFaces 3).

Comment: You can call setter in any action, for example as part of your actionListener. But usually it is not needed. For proper relation between datascroller and dataTable check IDs. In your code id of dataTable missing, but `for` attribute of datascroller is used.